# Open EXR does not produce desired header

Tags: python, scripting, export, file-format

I am using these nodes for the production of many iterated multichannel openEXR files:

[image]

The script is very similar to this:

```
def take_picture(index):
    bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
    tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
    nodes = tree.nodes
    links = tree.links

    # create layer + metadata nodes
    rl = nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')    

    l_node = nodes.new('CompositorNodeValue')
    l_node.label = 'Wavelength'
    l_node.name = 'Lambda'
    l_node.location = 300, 0
    l_node.outputs['Value'].default_value = 5

    # output node  
    f = nodes.new('CompositorNodeOutputFile')
    f.label = 'EXR Multichannel'
    f.name = 'OutFile'
    f.format.file_format = 'OPEN_EXR_MULTILAYER' 

    f.file_slots.new('Lambda')
    f.file_slots.new("image_" + index)

    # Links
    links.new(l_node.outputs['Value'], f.inputs['Lambda'])
    links.new(rl.outputs['Image'], f.inputs['image_'+index])

    # set filepath + name + render
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = '//Rendered images/Test/im_%s' % index
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)
```

Running the script creates multichannel .exr in the correct destination folder with the correct name, but all node-related headers are missing. The header does not include 'Sun_Int', 'Lambda', 'Lai_FOV' etc ... So I cannot acces any of the values that I wanted to be saved with the image itself.
If I include metadata note or enable some of the metadata in the UI to be included, these do appear in the file header. Only for some reason there is a very annoying "b" added in front of everything, so if I type a note "hello" and I call `print(file.header()['Note'])` in python, I get " b'hello' " instead of just 'hello'. This is also true for the camera name, Blender version etc.

Comment: The `b''` notation indicates that you are looking at bytes, and not characters. You can convert bytes to characters by using `thebytes.decode('utf8')`. Of course you have to choose the right encoding.

Comment: @dr.Sybren Thank you! Can you tell me how to choose the encoding? Should this be done in Python, or in the Blender script when I create the file?

Comment: I couldn't find an indication whether OpenEXR dictates any encoding, so it probably depends on what you put in. It's probably safe to use utf8.